# Why does rails truncate invalid arguments for where when generating SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Why is rails truncating the company id in the SQL?

```
0> Company.where(id: '123bad').to_sql
=> "SELECT \"companies\".* FROM \"companies\" WHERE \"companies\".\"id\" = 123"
```

id is a bigint.

Honestly, this seems like a potential security concern to me. But I assume there is a good reason for doing this. What is going on here?

Comment: Rails will coerce the values if the primary key is an integer. This is documented for [`.find`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find). I'm not quite sure how this would be a security concern.  If a user entering `'123bad'` gets access to something they shouldn't its not Rails fault.

Comment: Looks like this is a ruby thing... turns out `to_i` does this as well. `'asdf'.to_i == 1` as well. Disappointing, but I guess that's the way it is.

Comment: If you want to avoid coercion you can use `.where('id = ?', '123bad')`. But then your database might complain.

Comment: @Adverbly: "`'asdf'.to_i == 1` as well" - nope, this is false. I am also not seeing how this is a security concern.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry I meant `==0`. my mistake. @max Yes a DB error would be preferable. `Integer('123bad')` also raises on the `to_i` side.

Comment: Are you saying that you would prefer to cast all your own variables? How about: `where(some_date: Date.new(2021,9,10))` would you prefer to have to call `strftime` or `where(name: 12)` you would prefer to call `to_s`? If so I am certain you could fork the db adapter and remove the casting. A simple place to start would be define [`_quote`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L224) as `def _quote(value); value; end` then fix `_type_cast`

Answer (score 0):

The question asked is "Why?" and "What is going on here?"

The reason is that active record takes string representation of numbers (integers in this case) and does the ruby `to_i` method on that input.

The ruby `to_i` method is doing the truncation.

There is not a security issue as it is not possible to send anything other than an integer as the output of the ruby `to_i` method.

There is a potential data integrity issue if it succeeds on bad input when maybe it should fail to protect the data.  This is not so much of an issue with a query but and update like this could be a problem:

```
Company.where(id: params[:id]).update_all( ... )
```

This might work when supplied garbage, when it would be better to fail.

However issues like this are not the responsibility of the database services to protect you from.  It is the responsibility of the developer writing the calling code.